# Wordpress MU+MAMP error establishing database connection

Tags: mysql, apache, mamp, wordpress

I'm trying to set up a local environment for a Wordpress MU-site.

When I'm trying to use the default apache/mysql-ports. I get the error

```
Error establishing database connection
```

When I'm trying to use MAMP-default ports, I have to specify the port in the header:
http://dev.iris.se:8888/

In that case, I get the Wordpress-error

```
Multisite only works without the port number in the URL.
```

This is only shown when if the correct database-settings are entered in wp-config, indicating that the connection to the database is established.

I have tried Running on port 80(default apache) and port mySQL on 8889(default MAMP). I have also tried specifying the mamp-port in the config-file:

```
localhost:8889
127.0.0.1:8889
```

Is there anybody who doesn't know why I can connect to the database?
Is there a way to run the site on port 8888 without specifying it in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple websites running on my MAMP machine, and have found it easiest to use the default Apache and MAMP settings.

And you don't want to specify MAMP porting in this way through the config-file, instead modifying your /etc/hosts file on your main Macintosh computer. You shouldn't modify anything beyond the `fe80::1%lo0   localhost`, as it would mess up the way the hosting is read on your computer. You type your new virtual host below that line, the /etc/hosts file looking similar to this:

```
##
# Host Database 
# 
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry. 
## 
127.0.0.1         localhost
255.255.255.255   broadcasthost 
::1               localhost 
fe80::1%lo0       localhost 
127.0.0.1         localhost
127.0.0.1         examplesite.local
```

You can name examplesite.local however you want, this is the URL which will display your website in the browser. You save those changes to the /etc/hosts file, then going to the httpd.conf in your Apache folder (the location of the file being in Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf). You then add virtual hosts to the bottom of the file, with code like this, modifying the name examplesite.local to, again, whatever you want the URL to display in the browser:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/examplesitename"
ServerName examplesite.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Once you make these changes to the httpd.conf file, make sure to reboot your MAMP, as the Apache server needs to take these changes into effect.

Here is the website I use since I forget command-line in order to edit the /etc/hosts file and the steps I presented to you in more detail: http://sawmac.com/mamp/virtual/

Here's what the original /etc/hosts file off of the Macintosh looks like in case you ever lost it: http://thecoredump.org/2011/09/editing-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-lion/

Also, make sure you have a separate database, user for the database, and folder in the htdocs folder for each website you run on MAMP.

Hope this helps you get up and running!

Comment: @KristofferNolgren in your wp-config.php file, did you also modify it to reflect the database name and user for that particular website? Are you trying to run multiple WordPress websites on one database?